# Sympy does not simplify an expression with a symbol divided by the square root of its square

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have a problem with `sympy` simplification. See the code below.
When I substitute expression under `sqrt` with something, it becomes "unbreakable". For example, in the last line of code I multiplied expression by `f0` and simplified the result. `f0` in numerator and `sqrt(f0**2)` in denominator did not get simplified out even though `f0` is declared as `nonnegative`. What did I do wrong and how do I substitute expressions without having this effect?

Code ([pretty version with rendered equations](https://gist.github.com/seregaxvm/23ba4a7672a14182894823c38cb6291d)):

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import pi

>>> init_printing(use_unicode=True)
>>> L0, Csum0, f0 = symbols("L0 C_{{\\Sigma}0} f0", nonnegative=True)
>>> equation = sqrt(L0)
>>> equation
  ____
╲╱ L₀

>>> substitute = solve(Eq(1/(2*pi*sqrt(L0)*sqrt(Csum0)), f0), L0, dict=1)[0]
>>> substitute
⎧              1           ⎫
⎪L₀: ──────────────────────⎪
⎨                      2  2⎬
⎪    4⋅C_{{\Sigma}0}⋅f₀ ⋅π ⎪
⎩                          ⎭

>>> equation = equation.subs(substitute)
>>> equation
     ______________________
    ╱          1
   ╱  ────────────────────
  ╱                   2  2
╲╱    C_{{\Sigma}0}⋅f₀ ⋅π
───────────────────────────
             2

>>> simplify(equation*f0)
        ______________________
       ╱          1
f₀⋅   ╱  ────────────────────
     ╱                   2  2
   ╲╱    C_{{\Sigma}0}⋅f₀ ⋅π
──────────────────────────────
               2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancelling `f0/sqrt(f0**2)` is not legitimate when f0 is 0. To ensure this cancellation is allowed, declare f0 to be positive, not just nonnegative.

Also, importing `pi` from sympy.abc makes pi a generic symbol with no specific meaning; in particular, it's not known to be positive. SymPy already has `pi` (mathematical constant) built-in, and knows it's a positive number. So removing the import from `sympy.abc` improves  simplification.

```
from sympy import *
L0, Csum0, f0 = symbols("L0 C_{{\\Sigma}0} f0", positive=True)
equation = sqrt(L0)
substitute = solve(Eq(1/(2*pi*sqrt(L0)*sqrt(Csum0)), f0), L0, dict=1)[0]
equation = equation.subs(substitute)
simplify(equation*f0)
```

returns

```
1/(2*pi*sqrt(C_{{\Sigma}0}))
```